# MongoDB aggregation with nested array of objects property with date

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have data something like this

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("52ed12c144aecc4bf004d0b6"),
  "active": true,
  "name": "woslo",
 "specialDays": [
  {
  "_id": ObjectId("5f0576196198a715b0a72c14")
  "status": true
  "date": 2020-07-08T04:00:00.000+00:00
  },
  {
  "_id": ObjectId("5f05a3726198a715b0a72c94")
  "status": false
  "date": 2020-07-09T04:00:00.000+00:00
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to fetch records using this query

> ```
>    db.serviceProviders.aggregate([
>     {
>       $match: {
>             specialDays: {
>               $elemMatch: {
>                 $or: [
>                   {
>                     $and: [
>                       {
>                         date:  model.date // 2020-07-09T06:00:00.000Z
>                       },
>                       {
>                         status: true
>                       }
>                     ]
>                   },
>                   {
>                     date: {
>                       $ne:  model.date //2020-07-09T06:00:00.000Z
>                     }
>                   }
>                 ]
>               }
>             }
>           }
>         }
>   ]);
> ```

**Scenario is** : if date is present in specialDays array and the status should be true , or date should not be in specialDays Object's array then fetch this record.
But every time it's fetching the same record that is above even status is false or date is present in array.
Would you please help me how to figure it out, I tried a lot of queries in Mongo compass aggregation with **ISODate('2020-07-08')** but still not working.
Thank you
Happy Coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with your `$ne` condition. If status is false, then your `$ne` condition is true. Since it is logical OR, you are getting the output.

How about [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/utaGgGV7rad)?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      specialDays: {
        $elemMatch: {
          $or: [
            {
              $and: [
                {
                  date: new Date("2020-07-09T04:00:00.000+00:00")
                },
                {
                  status: true
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              date: {//Changes here
                $gte: new Date("2020-07-09T06:00:00.000+00:00"),
                $lte: new Date("2020-07-09T23:59:59.000+00:00")
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

OR

[this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7EUYnYATZT7)

Another reason for your `$ne` condition is true because it satisfies your first array element in `specialDays` array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      specialDays: {
        $elemMatch: {
          $or: [
            {
              $and: [
                {
                  date: new Date("2020-07-09T04:00:00.000+00:00")
                },
                {
                  status: true
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              $and: [
                {
                  date: {
                    $ne: new Date("2020-07-09T04:00:00.000+00:00")
                  }
                },
                {
                  status: false
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks to you man :), it solved my problem.

Comment: Glad, it helped. Happy coding @TanzeelSaleem